# Magento Product custom attribute options not showing up in admin

Tags: admin, product-attribute, custom, ce-1.9.2.1

In my Magento ce 1.9.2.1 website, I have created many product custom attributes by setup-upgrade scripts like below:

```
<?php
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', 'Business Directory', 'Business Directory', 1000);

$attribute_set_id = $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Business Directory');

$attribute_group_id = $installer->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, 'Business Directory');

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'city', array(
    'label'             => 'City',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'attribute_set'     => 'Business Directory',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'default'           => '',
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => '1',
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'option'     => array (
                        0 => array("Please Select City...")
                    ),
));

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'city', 'is_filterable', 1);

$attribute_id = $installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'city');

$installer->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId = 'catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'postcode', array(
    'label'             => 'Postcode',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'attribute_set'     => 'Business Directory',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'default'           => '',
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => '1',
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'option'     => array (
                        0 => array("Please Select Postcode...")
                    ),
));

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'postcode', 'is_filterable', 1);

$attribute_id = $installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'postcode');

$installer->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId = 'catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);

$installer->endSetup();

unset($installer);
```

As you can see, both the attributes are `select`(dropdown) and both have no values initially when they are created(this is my custom key criteria, empty attributes dropdown only).

But when I populate them programmatically from frontend form, their values doesn't show up in Admin >> Catalog >> Attributes in their forms. They still show no options in admin, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
'option'     => array (
    0 => array("Please Select City...")
),
```

to

```
'option'     => array (
    'values' => array(
        0 => array("Please Select City...")
     )
),
```

Comment: Btw, you also should replace 'type' => 'varchar' to 'type' => 'int'

Comment: Did that but still it doesn't add new options or updates existing ones in backend from frontend form.

Comment: You cannot add attribute options from frontend. If "Please Select City..." didn't appear as attribute's value, then you should remove that install script and run it again

Comment: I ran it three times already, but no luck adding from frontend.

Comment: You are trying to add new value (which previously never existed in attribute's options), right? If so, it is wrong. You can't add new value from frontend. You can just set one of already existing values to one of products

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign product attribute in `group`

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', "price_status", array(
'group' => 'Group Name', //you can also use "General"
'type'       => 'int',
'input'      => 'select',
'label'      => 'Allow check price ?',
'visible' => 1,  
'sort_order' => 10,
'visible' => 1,
'required' => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,
'searchable' => 0,
'filterable' => 0,
'comparable' => 0,
'visible_on_front' => 0,
'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
'is_configurable' => 1,
'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
'option' => array (
    'values' => array(
        0 => 'No',
        1 => 'Yes',
    )
),
```

May be it will help you.